# Keep old hard drive trays?

Tags: hard-drive, hp

Just wondering if there's any reason to hang on to some old Compaq hard drive trays.  These came from a server that's no longer in use.

Is eBay the only place to check to see if anyone is interested, or are there other/better places to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't throw them away until I'm not using any servers that have that specific model of trays.

The reason is that once you throw them away, it's nearly impossible to get the parts from the mfg again without purchasing drives with them, so you're essentially at the mercy of Ebay or craigslist to get the parts you need. That's never a good situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've always kept a bunch of old stuff around to use as spares, but in about 18 years, I've only every needed something a couple of times.  I **still** have some 5.25" high density floppy drives, some original DEC Storageworks drive cases, a DDS2 DAT drive, a Jaz drive and a couple disks, a couple USB Zip drives, a couple VT420 terminals, an old Alphaserver...

Answer (score 0):

We haven't found a use for them. As we decommission old Compaq servers, our own spare pile builds up so we have no need to go looking for replacements. The market is probably very minimal for them.